# Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeb

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error with Android Studio with an app I've developed and it was working yesterday and today I get this error with every app I try to launch via Android Studio. I have made no changes in my gradle file since yesterday and I don't use Firebase (I have seen other questions with this error and people mentioning Firebase). Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I reverted back to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

from

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
```

Changing only this has allowed my app to run. I'm not entirely sure why it was working the other day, but this has solved my issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

In your `project` gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' //update to latest version
```

And in `module` gradle file, update dependencies version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'//here is an example
```

Comment: I have all my dependencies using their latest respective versions. For your first suggestion, `compile` does not work. Do you perhaps mean having this be `classpath` in the dependencies field? I have added this line to the project gradle file and I still get the same error. The error is claiming a duplicate classes issue but I cannot find a duplicate class and as I mention in the question, I made no changes from yesterday which had everything working. This is the URL the error points to: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes